# Iterate an object that is the result of and observable

Tags: javascript, validation, object, observable

i am trying to iterate in an object that is the result of and observable.

The problem is that i get the message Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'.

```
 userValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {

  return  this.un.unidades.pipe(
    map(res => {
      res.forEach(element => {
        // Here it fails!! It says Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'.
      });
      console.log(res) // Array of objects
      console.log(typeof(res)) // Output: object
              })
  )
};
```

If i try to use the method for each with subscribing the observable it works.
But when i use pipe(map), it does not.

How can i iterate over the object?

Comment: Is this RxJS, Redux?  Could you add the appropriate tag?

Comment: This is not valid Javascript.

Comment: can you add the sample result i.e what exactly you get in `res` using JSON.stringify() function

Comment: It is RxJS. [{"bd_id":1,"bd_Codigo":1,"bd_Valor":"mg"},{"bd_id":2,"bd_Codigo":2,"bd_Valor":"ul"},{"bd_id":4,"bd_Codigo":4,"bd_Valor":"FQSS"},{"bd_id":5,"bd_Codigo":5,"bd_Valor":"Otro"},{"bd_id":6,"bd_Codigo":6,"bd_Valor":"l"},{"bd_id":7,"bd_Codigo":10,"bd_Valor":"ppb"},{"bd_id":8,"bd_Codigo":45,"bd_Valor":"ppm"},{"bd_id":9,"bd_Codigo":11,"bd_Valor":"pp"},{"bd_id":10,"bd_Codigo":780,"bd_Valor":"iiooooooo"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but looking at the interface of the observable it seems like it is an object whoes properties are arrays of objects. The error is pointing at that too. If we could see the result of the console log.

Try to log res.length to make sure it is an array though I imagine it will say that length doesn't exist on the object.

If it's an object you have to iterate the keys or use Object.values(res).forEach and then iterate the arrays.

Comment: It is just like you say. res.length doesn't exist. I will try with Object.values(res).forEach. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful. Can you accept the answer as the best answer?